# Trouble running streamlit

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, streamlit

I am trying out streamlit for the first time ever on my windows machine. I just saved the below code as a .py file.

```
import streamlit as st
st.title("First Streamlit Web Application")
```

I opened the command window through the Anaconda navigator and when I run this file what I get is a brower window with a long code type text:

```
{
"cells":[
0:{
"cell_type":"code"
"execution_count":1
"metadata":{}
"outputs":[]
"source":[
0:"import streamlit as st "
1:"st.title("First Streamlit Web Application")"
]
}
]
"metadata":{
"kernelspec":{
"display_name":"Python 3"
"language":"python"
"name":"python3"
}
"language_info":{
"codemirror_mode":{
"name":"ipython"
"version":3
}
"file_extension":".py"
"mimetype":"text/x-python"
"name":"python"
"nbconvert_exporter":"python"
"pygments_lexer":"ipython3"
"version":"3.7.4"
}
}
"nbformat":4
"nbformat_minor":2
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "I opened the command window through the Anaconda navigator"? You need to start the streamlit server: in the command line, `streamlit run <name-of-python-file>`. Running the streamlit server itself has nothing to do with Anaconda.

Comment: did you read documentation for `streamlit` how to use it? It runs web server which may generate HTML and send to browser OR it may send HTML with JavaScript which gets information about elements on page as JSON data - like in your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted, it appears that you have saved this as a Jupyter Notebook somehow, instead of a plain-text Python script. Create a plain-text file not using Jupyter (with VSCode, Atom, or any other text editor) and save it as `app.py`, then run `streamlit run app.py`

Answer (score -1):

You need to save it as python file with extension .py

Comment: looks like a comment

Comment: In the question: `I just saved the below code as a .py file`. In the other answer: `save it as app.py`. I'm afraid that your answer adds nothing new.